# Crash in onCreateView DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

So I created a fragment, and there's a button on it. When clicked, it pops up a `DialogFragment`. My problem is that it crashes when I run it.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
    Button off = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btnOff);

    off.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            OneFragment.this.onOff(View v);//error here
        }
    });
    return view;
}

public void onOff(View v){
    new OffButton().show(getFragmentManager(),"off");
}
```

Comment: You should post the stack trace associated with your crash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your Button is inside fragment_one.xml, so you have to search the button there:

```
Button off = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnOff);
```

and inside your your onClick() just

```
onOff(v);
```

but i dont understand what you want to do inside onOff(..)

Comment: why vote down when i try to help?? At least comment!